# Convert Python list to Json object

Tags: python, dataframe

I have three lists `emojiLink`, `emojiTitle`, `emojiDescription` in my code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://www.emojimeanings.net/list-smileys-people-whatsapp")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

emojiLink = []
emojiTitle = []
emojiDescription = []

for tableRow in soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"class": "ugc_emoji_tr"}):
    for img in tableRow.findChildren("img"):
        emojiLink.append(img['src'])



for tableData in soup.find_all("td"):
    for boldTag in tableData.findChildren("b"):
        emojiTitle.append(boldTag.text)

for tableRow in soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"class": "ugc_emoji_tr"}):
    for tabledata in tableRow.findChildren("td"):
        if tabledata.has_attr("id"):
            k = tabledata.text.strip().split('\n')[-1]
            l = k.lstrip()
            emojiDescription.append(l)
```

I want to convert these lists into a Json object which gonna look like...

`{{"link": "emojiLink[0]", "title": "emojiTitle[0]", "desc": "emojiDescription[0]"},{"link": "emojiLink[1]", "title": "emojiTitle[1]", "desc": "emojiDescription[1]"}..........} so on...`

I am not getting to how to do this?

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: Your expected output is neither a valid JSON nor a valid python dictionary.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You should localize your issue.  Only provide enough information that is required to solve your problem.  Really what you want to know is how to export a python list into a json object.  Also validate any JSON you put on there and beautify it with an online JSON beautifier.  These are all just relevant tips to keeping viewers around, not confusing them, and reducing the amount of comments engineered around typos.  Also Python is a general purpose language that can be compiled very easily.  It would be beneficial to provide a MWE(Minimum Working Example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One by one access each element from list and put it into some dict and at the end append to a list:

```
import json

# some example lists
em_link = ['a', 'b', 'c']
em_title = ['x', 'y', 'z']
em_desc = [1,2,3]

arr = []
for i,j,k in zip(em_link, em_title, em_desc):
    d = {}
    d.update({"link": i})
    d.update({"title": j})
    d.update({"desc": k})
    arr.append(d)

print(json.dumps(arr))
```

Output:

```
[{"link": "a", "title": "x", "desc": 1}, {"link": "b", "title": "y", "desc": 2}, {"link": "c", "title": "z", "desc": 3}]
```

Answer (score 3):

This returns an array of JSON objects based off of Chandella07's answer.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("https://www.emojimeanings.net/list-smileys-people-whatsapp")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

emojiLinkList = []
emojiTitleList = []
emojiDescriptionList = []
jsonData = []

for tableRow in soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"class": "ugc_emoji_tr"}):
    for img in tableRow.findChildren("img"):
        emojiLinkList.append(img['src'])

for tableData in soup.find_all("td"):
    for boldTag in tableData.findChildren("b"):
        emojiTitleList.append(boldTag.text)

for tableRow in soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"class": "ugc_emoji_tr"}):
    for tabledata in tableRow.findChildren("td"):
        if tabledata.has_attr("id"):
            k = tabledata.text.strip().split('\n')[-1]
            l = k.lstrip()
            emojiDescriptionList.append(l)

for link, title, desc in zip(emojiLinkList, emojiTitleList, emojiDescriptionList):
    dict = {"link": link, "title": title, "desc": desc}
    jsonData.append(dict)

print(json.dumps(jsonData, indent=2))
```

Data Example:

```
{
    "link": "https://www.emojimeanings.net/img/emojis/purse_1f45b.png",
    "title": "Wallet",
    "desc": "After the shopping trip, the money has run out or the wallet was forgotten at home. The accessory keeps loose money but also credit cards or make-up. Can refer to shopping or money and stand for femininity and everything girlish."
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your dict format. `{{...},{...}}` is not a valid format, `[{...},{...}]` is valid.

Regarding the merging logic:

```py
for i in zip([1,2,3], ["a", "b"], [8,9,10]):
    print(i)
```

... will output ...

```
(1, 'a', 8)
(2, 'b', 9)
```

Try something like that:

```py
out = []
for i in zip(emojiLink, emojiTitle, emojiDescription):
    out.append({"link": i[0], ...})
```

---

You can use the `json` library to read/write in json format.

```py
import json

with open('./smthn.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump({"a": "dictionary"}, f)
```

https://devtut.github.io/python/json-module.html#storing-data-in-a-file

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I noticed that after writing the second part ^^ Now I have added the actual answer

Answer (score 0):

So, you want a list of dictionary records?  If you're sure all of the lists are the same length, you can do:

```
gather = []
for l,t,d in zip(emojiLink,emojiTitle,emojiDescription):
    gather.append( {"link":l, "title":t, "desc":d} )
json.dump( gather, open("myrecord.json","w") )
```